# Woocommerce query by price range and custom meta key

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I've written a function to get products by price range. All works, but now I need add a extra meta key, that will be like 50 - 100 and featured, but code is not returning any products. What is wrong on this code?

```
    function product_price_filter_box($attr) {
    $limit = intval($attr['limit']);
    $min = intval($attr['min']);
    $max = intval($attr['max']);
    $query = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => array($min, $max),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'featured',
                'value'     => '1',
                'compare'   => '=',
            ),
        )
    );

    $wpquery = new WP_Query($query);
    while ( $wpquery->have_posts() ) : $wpquery->the_post(); global $product;
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();

}
add_shortcode( 'product_price_filter_box', 'product_price_filter_box' );
```

Answer (score 2):

The featured product's meta key is `_featured`, but you are using `featured` in your meta query. This will return no products, since the key doesn't exist.

Also, as far as I know, the value of the key is `yes`, so your arguments should be like this:

```
array(
    'key'       => '_featured',
    'value'     => 'yes',
)
```

Another note, is to use the proper way to get the shortcode's attribute. You can do so by using `shortcode_atts()` function. Here is the syntax for your case:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'limit' => '20',
        'min' => '1'
        'max' => '2'
    ), 
    $atts, 
    'product_price_filter_box' 
);

$limit = intval($atts['limit']);
$min = intval($atts['min']);
$max = intval($atts['max']);
```

You might want to limit the maximum posts a user can get. This can be done by using the `min()` function:

```
$limit = min(20, $limit);
```

And a final note. If you are using `WP_Query`, you should use `wp_reset_postdata();` instead of `wp_reset_query();`, which is used after you use `query_posts();`.

Comment: ps: we could add that OP is missing the  default attribute handling, range validation and is not returning the html.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I don't understand. But he mentioned that his range validation works fine?

Comment: e.g. the limit here can be anything, so if there are 1M posts then the user can fetch 1M posts through the shortcode and crash the site. Also if the attributes are missing then there's a PHP notice. Also the shortcode should return the output, not echo it.

Comment: Ah you mean validation of parameters :) Sure, I'll add that too.

Comment: That is only example, custom meta key can bet anything. Without custom meta key, code is working normaly, so i need that code also take meta key.

Comment: So, If you don't set the custom meta keys, does my solution return featured products?

Comment: Yes. It works normal. http://phonearena.lv/en/ As you can see, there is custom price tabs. But now i fixed my self this. Strange is that, that numeric true or false is not working, but when i do custom field show and value Yes, its working. 

array(
                'key'       => 'show',
                'value'     => 'Yes',
                'compare'   => '=',
            ),

Comment: Well then, glad to hear your figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Since WC 3.0.0

You can use `wc_get_min_max_price_meta_query()`. Woocommerce will create the price min/max meta_query for you. This also includes a tax check.

More info [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_min_max_price_meta_query.html#740-777).

Below an example that matches the OP question:

```
$meta_query = array(
  'relation'    => 'AND',
  array(
    'key'       => 'your_custom_meta_key',
    'value'     => '1',
    'compare'   => '=',
  ),
);
$meta_query[] = wc_get_min_max_price_meta_query(array(
  'min_price' => 100,
  'max_price' => 200,
));
$query = array(
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'post_type'       => 'product',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_query'      => $meta_query,
);
$wpquery = new WP_Query($query);
```

Comment: This function is deprecated since WC version 3.6.